# Reasons for getting Error Problems creating SAAJ object modle

Tags: saaj

I am using cx 2.7.5 and tomcat to deploy the WS. I am trying to access webservice via SOAP UI. I stuk in getting the error saying
      
         soap:Client
         Problems creating SAAJ object model

Could you please help me, in identifying what is the reason that I am getting this type of error.

Thans in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had some unclosed tags in the request. It works now.